# Angular2 - how to get json data from server and modify json prior to mapping

Tags: angular

In angular2 I don not get on how to modify this return:

1) This is my service.  Yes..I get the json object from the service I want.

```
getModel(modelId:any){
        return this._authHttp.get(this.getModelUrl(modelId)).map(res => res.json());
}
```

In my ngOnInit() this is how I make the call.  It works however I dont understand what I am doing regarding this part: model_initials => this.model_initials = model_initials

```
this._modelService.getModel(this.model_id)
            .subscribe(model_initials => this.model_initials = model_initials,
            null,() => { this.isLoading = false; });
```

What I need is this.  I need the model initials as an object so I can modify it and then map to this.model_initials.

So in sum this is the data that I get back from the  server on init:

```
       {
        "available": "Q"
       }
```

Then maps to this.model_initials.

However I need to e.g. rename to

```
       {
        "availablenow": "Q"
       }
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could this like that:

```
getModel(modelId:any){
    return this._authHttp.get(this.getModelUrl(modelId))
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map(data => {
        return data.map(d => {
          let mappedD = Object.assign({}, d);
          mappedD.availablenow = mappedD.available;
          delete mappedD.available;
          return mappedD;
        }
      };
}
```